# What is the difference between 'ls *.py" and "ls *py"?

Tags: bash, cygwin, ls

This happens in cygwin (CYGWIN_NT-5.1 MYPC 1.7.5(0.225/5/3) 2010-04-12 19:07 i686 Cygwin)

First command, `ls *.py` shows nothing

```
$ ls *.py
ls: cannot access *.py: No such file or directory
```

First command,  `ls *.py` runs in the same location, shows the following

```
$ ls *py
LICENSE.txt    _cpchecker.pyc   _cperror.pyc    _cpserver.py          _cptree.pyc         favicon.ico
__init__.py    _cpconfig.py     _cplogging.py   _cpserver.pyc         _cpwsgi.py          lib
__init__.pyc   _cpconfig.pyc    _cplogging.pyc  _cpthreadinglocal.py  _cpwsgi.pyc         process
_cpcgifs.py    _cpdispatch.py   _cpmodpy.py     _cptools.py           _cpwsgi_server.py   scaffold
_cpcgifs.pyc   _cpdispatch.pyc  _cprequest.py   _cptools.pyc          _cpwsgi_server.pyc  wsgiserver
_cpchecker.py  _cperror.py      _cprequest.pyc  _cptree.py            cherryd
```

These are files in a subdirectory cherrypy

I did not alias `ls` in any way (running `/usr/bin/ls` gives the same results)

So, the question, why the difference? I do not expect `ls` to run recursively without the `-R` flag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because running `ls` with a folder name will list the contents of the folder(s) that match your argument.

Using `*` as a wildcard, any folders ending in `py` would have their contents listed, such as `cherrypy, crappy, bumpy` etc.

If multiple folders match the criteria, it will show you the folder names as well:

```
[~/ex]$touch bumpy/1
[~/ex]$touch sloppy/2
[~/ex]$touch cherrypy/3 cherrypy/4 cherrypy/5
[~/ex]$ls *py
bumpy:
1

cherrypy:
3  4  5

sloppy:
2
[~/ex]$
```

You did not have any folders or files directly in your current folder which ended in `.py` when you ran the first command, hence the output.